# Will the performance be worse if bitwise operations are used in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

There are several boolean columns in one table. For convenience in my code, I want to use one column to replace all of them. In the new column, each bit represents an original boolean column. But if I do like this, I must do bitwise operation in the where clause, so I can't use index for it.

Will the performance be worse if bitwise operations are used in MYSQL?

Comment: *Java programmers "discover" this idea pretty often. Database designers know better.* You should read the pro's and cons [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/db-optimization-with-2-to-the-power-of-n-approach-clarification)

Comment: Ahhh, again another person that spends most time optimizing things that matter least :-) ... in better case. In worse case it will even slow the thing down. Do it cleanly and define separate columns. Also it's possible that the database engine will use the bitwise operations for it even if you declare it as columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
I must do bitwise operation in the where clause, so I can't use index for it.
```

You answered your own question. If your query does not use an index, it means mysql will have to check every actual value stored to see if it matches, which will be a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

You've already answered your question - `so I can't use an index for it` - yes, in most cases performance will be harmed.